ERROR: Could not build wheels for gensim, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects, How can I resolve this in google colab
The Error is appearing when I tried to install nlg-eval package using the command:
!pip install git+https://github.com/Maluuba/nlg-eval.git@master


I tried installing wheels explicitly before installing nlg-eval package using the command:
!pip install wheels

I also tried installing the gensim separately using the command:
pip install --use-pep517 gensim==3.8.3

I even installed setup tools using the command:
!pip install setuptools

But nothing is working.
How to resolve it?

You haven't mentioned what Python you're using.
But, if you're trying to use (~4 year old) Gensim-3.8.3 from some reason, perhaps because the (~3 year old) nlg-eval project only works with that version, be advised that at the time of its release, the latest Python it supported (and for which prebuilt wheels might be available) was Python 3.8: https://pypi.org/project/gensim/3.8.3/
Rolling your working environment back to that Python version might be the most-simple way to match the expectations of the nlg-eval code you're using.
Alternatively, if for some reason you must get a local install/build of Gensim-3.8.3 working in some non-supported Python, that might be possible with effort.
But, you'd have to provide far more info in your question(s) about the results of your attempts (like pip install --use-pep515 gensim=3.8.3) than just "nothing is working", because that gives no hint of what, if anything, might be failing, at what step, in your particular OS/Python/libraries/tools setup.

colab usually uses Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0], and I ran in to the same issue when i opened a new colab. the problem seems to be in the c compilation (run pip with -v), and interestingly version 3.8.2 installs fine but 4.0.0 has the same issue.

If via some fortunate alignment with the assumptions of the Colba environment, Gensim-3.8.2 installs where 3.8.3 does not, can you perhaps use 3.8.2 for your purposes? (All of these are worse choices than the latest Gensim, but if you're stuck with older Gensim due to other code that's too hard to update, the fixes between 3.8.2 and 3.8.3 may be no big loss.)

If Colab only uses Pythons >= 3.10, but Gensim-3.8.3 was only built & tested through Python 3.9, it may require an arbitrary amount of custom troubleshooting/engineering to get older Gensim working there. THe same effort might be better spent updating the code which uses older Gensim to instead use the latest. The code changes are usually pretty straightforward, & tips for most required edits at at: https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

OTOH, if building older Gensim on Colab is absolutely required, details of specifically how it is failing moreso than "ERROR: failed building wheel for gensim" would be required to make suggestions. This might require trying to build gensim alone, in some sort of more-verbose mode, and reviewing/addressing each more-detailed error in turn.

I was able to reproduce by just opening a new colab and running the given pip command with -v. It produces a bunch of c compiler errors, which leads me to believe it uses an unsupported compiler for the gensim source. Gensim ~= 3.8.3 is mandated by nlg-eval, meaning that 3.8.3 is the only candidate. Attempting to install this prpduces the same error. Unfortunately I was not able to downgrade to python 3.8, but the OP may have more luck :)

Looking back at the Gensim 3.8.2 to 3.8.3 release notes, the functional changes were minimal - it was chiefly to fix some build issues for Python 2.x. So patching nlg-eval to accept 3.8.2, if it offered other benefits (like a successful local build), might leave nlg-eval working fine. Fixing the actual compilations issue will require digging into the specific errors – which I might get a chance to do in coming days, but no guarantees (esp if problems not trivial).

Short answer is you need an older version of Python, e.g. 3.11 because they haven't created the wheels for Python 3.12 yet. check Installation Error: Failed building wheel for gensim #3510.
